# Replace query string with file extension using htaccess Rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this link `https://career.guru99.com/top-50-c-sharp-interview-questions-answers/?format=pdf`

I want to redirect it to `https://www.guru99.com/pdf/c-sharp-interview-questions.pdf`

I created the following htaccess rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} format=pdf [NC]
RewriteRule ^c-sharp-interview-questions.html  /pdf/c-sharp-interview-questions.pdf? [R=301,L]
```

But the challenge is I have 100+ links and I will have to manually add so many entries in the htacess which also slow down the site. Is there some regular expression that can help with this?

I want `/?format=pdf` to be replaced with `.pdf`

Comment: Your rule doesn’t match the requested path here in the first place. (Or your problem description is not acurate.)

Comment: I have Redirect on Following Links - https://test8.guru99.com/top-50-c-sharp-interview-questions-answers/?format=pdf

But It was not redirecting correctly it's 404 error.

Redirect correct link is  - https://www.test2.demoguru99.com/pdf/c-sharp-interview-questions.pdf

Comment: I have used following code 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} format=pdf [NC]
RewriteRule ^c-sharp-interview-questions.html  /pdf/c-sharp-interview-questions.pdf? [R=301,L]

Comment: @anubhava, yes changes on host name

Answer (score 1):

***1st Solution:*** Try following in case you are hitting `http://localhost:80/top-50-c-sharp-interview-questions-answers/?format=pdf` in your browser. Change `[NC,L]` TO `[R=301,NC,L]` in case you want to redirect your URL in browser.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^career\.guru99\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^top-50-(.*)/?$ pdf/c-sharp-$1.%1 [NC,L]
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Could you please try following, written based on your shown samples(considering that you want to hit `http://localhost:80/pdf/c-sharp-interview-questions.pdf` in your browser).

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^career\.guru99\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(pdf)/([^.]*)\.(pdf)/?$ top-50-$1/?format=$2 [NC,L]
```

***NOTE:*** Either use 1st OR use 2nd solution at a time please. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: I have try to following solution but it was not work. I have Redirect on Following Links - https://test8.guru99.com/top-50-c-sharp-interview-questions-answers/?format=pdf

But It was not redirect on 404 error.

Redirect correct link is  - https://www.test2.demoguru99.com/pdf/c-sharp-interview-questions.pdf

Comment: @renishbhalodiya, could you please do let me know if you are getting any errors?

Comment: @renishbhalodiya, I have added redirection to new domain rule too now, kindly check it once and let me know how it goes now.

Comment: Our Url was not fixed on "top-50" words. for ex.- career.guru99.com/something-here/?format=pdf

Comment: @renishbhalodiya, ok could you please do give some examples of URLs here?

Comment: https://test8.guru99.com/expertadvance-level-qtp-uft-interview-questions/?format=pdf  to
https://www.test2.demoguru99.com/pdf/qtp.pdf   https://test8.guru99.com/top-35-advanced-software-testing-questions/?format=pdf to
https://www.test2.demoguru99.com/pdf/testing.pdf

Comment: @renishbhalodiya, sorry to bother but its not clear. If you could put it in this way like "I want to hit url `http://localhost:80/singh?test_blaetc` in browser and want to get `http://localhost:80/singhetcetc`" this is just an example, if you could do let me know in this manner then it will help us for better understanding.

Comment: Example 1- `https://test8.guru99.com/expertadvance-level-qtp-uft-interview-questions/?format=pdf` to Redirect on this page
`https://www.test2.demoguru99.com/pdf/qtp.pdf` Example 2- `https://test8.guru99.com/top-35-advanced-software-testing-questions/?format=pdf` to Redirect on this page
`https://www.test2.demoguru99.com/pdf/testing.pdf`

Comment: @renishbhalodiya, ok only 2 pages right exactly these ones? Kindly confirm once

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Although in the question they sate they "have 100+ links". These are presumably just 2 of those "100+ plus"!

Comment: @MrWhite, yeah, I believe that is what you and me both trying to figure out what could be Logic/conditions to make rules here :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yeah, and I'm not seeing a pattern here?! ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I want `/?format=pdf` to be replaced with `.pdf`

Although, in your example, that is not the only thing that is changing. You would also need to do the following:

1. Change the hostname from `career.guru99.com` to `www.guru99.com`.
2. Remove `top-50-` from the start of the URL-path.
3. Remove `-answers/` from the end of the URL-path.

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^career\.guru99\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^top-50-([\w-]+)-answers/?$ https://www.guru99.com/%1/$1.%1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

This would redirect a URL of the form:

```
https://career.guru99.com/top-50-something-here-answers/?format=pdf
```

to:

```
https://www.guru99.com/pdf/something-here.pdf
```

The `%1` backreference simply captures the "pdf" string from the query string (avoiding repetition) and this is used twice in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string.

The `$1` backreference captures the part of the URL-path after the `/top-50-` at the start of the URL-path and before the `-answers/` (trailing slash optional) at the end of the URL-path.

The `QSD` flag *discards* the query string from the redirected URL.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect before changing to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - so as to avoid potential caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteRule ^c-sharp-interview-questions.html .......
> ```

Where was the `.html` coming from in your example?

---

**UPDATE#1:** If the last URL-path segment is meant to form the filename as-is with nothing removed (as you seem to imply in comments) then the above rule can be simplified:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^career\.guru99\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=(pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+?)/?$ https://www.guru99.com/%1/$1.%1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

(However, this does contradict the example you posted in the question?)

---

**UPDATE#2:**

> ```
> https://test8.guru99.com/expertadvance-level-qtp-uft-interview-questions/?format=pdf
> https://www.test2.demoguru99.com/pdf/qtp.pdf
>
> https://test8.guru99.com/top-35-advanced-software-testing-questions/?format=pdf
> https://www.test2.demoguru99.com/pdf/testing.pdf
> ```

From these two examples there is no single pattern that can be applied that would map the source URL-path to the destination. For example, how would *you* describe in *natural language* how you get from `expertadvance-level-qtp-uft-interview-questions` to `qtp` and from `top-35-advanced-software-testing-questions` to `testing`?

Regular expressions are not magic. There needs to be an identifiable "pattern" that maps from A to B.

So you would need to perform these redirects individually. However, this can be streamlined so that it does not impact site performance. (Although even 100 such redirects written verbatum in `.htaccess` isn't too bad.)

You could internally rewrite requests that match the hostname (`test8.guru99.com`) and query string (`format=pdf`) to a script that processes the request and issues the redirect. OR, you could rewrite the request to a (private) subdirectory that contains a second `.htaccess` file that only has these specific redirects.

For example:

In your root `.htaccess` file, issue an internal rewrite to a subdirectory if it passes preliminary checks:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test8\.guru99\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=pdf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+?)/?$ redirect-pdf/$1 [QSD,L]
```

Create the subdirectory `/redirect-pdf` and in a secondary `.htaccess` file at `/redirect-pdf/.htaccess` create the specific redirects. Note that in the `RewriteRule` above I removed the (optional) trailing slash from the rewritten URL, so this should not be checked in the redirects below.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Set an env var to the base target
# (Just saves some bytes/repetition and easier to update)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=TARGET_BASE:https://www.test2.demoguru99.com/pdf]

# Redirects
RewriteRule ^expertadvance-level-qtp-uft-interview-questions$ %{ENV:TARGET_BASE}/qtp.pdf [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^top-35-advanced-software-testing-questions$ %{ENV:TARGET_BASE}/testing.pdf [R=302,L]
# etc.
# :

# If get to the end and nothing matched above then fail with a 404...?
```

You could use a backreference (if applicable) to save repetition if you wanted. For example:

```
# Redirects
RewriteRule ^expertadvance-level-(qtp)-uft-interview-questions$ %{ENV:TARGET_BASE}/$1.pdf [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^top-35-advanced-software-(testing)-questions$ %{ENV:TARGET_BASE}/$1.pdf [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Our Url was not fixed on "top-50" words. for ex.- https://career.guru99.com/something-here/?format=pdf   and 100+ links will redirect

Comment: So, how do you identify the target URL from the source URL? In the single example you posted in the question the only discernable difference would seem to be the removal of `top-50-` and `-answers/`, as I stated in my answer above. Are you now suggesting that there are different prefixes that should be removed? How do you identify a "prefix"? Or is the URL-path meant to remain the same? But then that contradicts with the example you posted in the question?

Comment: https://test8.guru99.com/expertadvance-level-qtp-uft-interview-questions/?format=pdf  to
https://www.test2.demoguru99.com/pdf/qtp.pdf   https://test8.guru99.com/top-35-advanced-software-testing-questions/?format=pdf to
https://www.test2.demoguru99.com/pdf/testing.pdf

Comment: There is no discernable pattern in those two redirects, so you would need to perform these redirects separately. However, this can be streamlined so that it does not impact performance and so that you don't need to repeat the `RewriteCond` directives for each redirect. I've updated my answer.